# Email Verify Process

Tags: php

I have a system with a "import from XLS" option, xls contains lakhs or n number of emails, the user uploads the file, which is added to a Queue (Queue::push). My problem is that i have set a cron in the windows scheduler which verify the emails in the list, Queue takes a while to process the emails to verify using dns records and mxhosts and so people will have to wait a lot. Let's say it takes hours to verify each file and there are 10 files in the Queue, the last one to upload will need to wait of hours. Is it safe to run multiple commands? The amount of process will vary as people start to use it more. Is there any other approach to have it run concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your CRON job to run every **n** seconds of time, by that CRON will be able to do the job concurrently without waiting for other previous jobs.

You might encounter race condition in this, in which one fill may get processed with by multiple jobs. To avoid this you will need to implement lock system on each processing record.

So if one CRON job or process accessing or processing file X then subsequent CRON should not take that file and pick the next file to process.

This way you can avoid long waiting time of the files.